# dlib в pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, heroku, pythonanywhere

пытаюсь выложить django приложение в котором используется библиотека dlib. Кто-нибудь нибудь знает как правильно ее установить на python anywhere. 
Или хотя бы на какую нибудь другую облачную платформу?

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что **DLib** написана на C++, а сервисы по запуску Питона вроде PythonAnywhere созданы именно для проектов на Питоне, и с поддержкой либ на Си и Плюсах и них всё непросто.

Где-то в 2014-м PythonAnywhere [говорили о возможном внедрении](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1131/) такого функционала, а в 2015-м [вроде даже внедрили](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/2656/). Также на PythonAnywhere предоставляется доступ к консоли, поэтому просто следуйте [инструкции по установке на GitHub'e](https://github.com/davisking/dlib#compiling-dlib-c-example-programs). Но честно говоря я сомневаюсь, что это сработает, так как DLib лезет глубоко в систему и требует значительных прав.

Нормальное решение: возьмите себе VPS и делайте там что угодно, в наше время это не дорого, заодно опыт будет полезный. Только учтите, что DLib работает даже не на всяком VPS – я брал Linux с виртуализацией на **OpenVZ**, а он выделяет системные ресурсы гибко и ограничивает низкоуровневые права, и установка DLib не прошла. Поэтому советую VPS с виртуализацией на **XEN**, который выделяет ресурсы чётко и перманентно, давая полный контроль на ними вашему виртуальному Линуксу. Ну или полноценный выделенный, dedicated сервер, если есть деньги и большие планы.

Comment: просто я учусь пока с нейросетями работать и для этого наверное покупать vps будет лишним

Comment: @rowwwansl тогда можно просто на своим компе всё делать :)